# spring security dynamic roles

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on spring mvc and spring security project. In our project roles and permissions will be stored in db and there are different roles there. I have written below code for restrict the access but all URL's are availing to all of them, please help me to restrict users based on their Granted authorities.

security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login  login-page="/login.jsp" 
                     login-processing-url="/login"
                     username-parameter="userName"
                     password-parameter="password"
                     authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                     authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailedHandler"
                     />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout=true"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied"/>
    </http>
```

Custom Authentication Provider

```
List<GrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if(userName.equals("admin")){
        System.out.println("++++++ admin user +++++");
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("/hello"));
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("/hello1"));
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("/hello2"));
    }else{
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("/hello"));
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("/hello1"));
    }
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName,null,AUTHORITIES);
```

In the above example now all users are able to access all url's, but pls help to restrict them to access only url's that are granted to him.

Comment: Please read docs of spring security http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity.

Comment: `SimpleGrantedAuthority` should take a role not a URL. Try to solve this. I also recommand you to take a look here : http://www.baeldung.com/security-spring

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<http use-expressions="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_MYCUSTOMROLE')"/>
    <form-login  login-page="/login.jsp" 
                 login-processing-url="/login"
                 username-parameter="userName"
                 password-parameter="password"
                 authentication-success-handler-  ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                 authentication-failure-handler-  ref="authenticationFailedHandler"
                 />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login.jsp?logout=true"/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied"/>
</http>
```

NOTE 1: use security name space for clarity and access attribute should have some role not url

instead of passing URl to GrantedAuthority pass some role, even you can do better just make an User pojo class and implements UserDetails that way you will avoid lots of boiler plate codes.